# unable to open xml after decryption 1 byte to many?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt XML, and after decryption I end up with 1 byte too many - probably because of padding. This is my code. How can I change this to make it work?

```
public byte[] encryptData(byte[] source,string key)
{
    byte[] btKeyInBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, btKeyInBytes);

    AesManaged encryptor = new AesManaged();
    encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

    using (MemoryStream encryptStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream encStream = new CryptoStream(encryptStream, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(rfc.GetBytes(16), rfc.GetBytes(16)), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            //Read from the input stream, then encrypt and write to the output stream.
            encStream.Write(source, 0, source.Length);
            encStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            encryptor.Clear();
        }
        encryptStream.Flush();
        encryptedSource = encryptStream.ToArray();
    }
    return encryptedSource;
}

public byte[] decryptData(byte[] source, string key)
{
    byte[] encryptedSource = null;

    byte[] btKeyInBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, btKeyInBytes);

    AesManaged encryptor = new AesManaged();
    encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

    using (MemoryStream encryptStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream encStream = new CryptoStream(encryptStream, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(rfc.GetBytes(16), rfc.GetBytes(16)), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            //Read from the input stream, then encrypt and write to the output stream.
            encStream.Write(source, 0, source.Length);
            encStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            encryptor.Clear();
        }
        encryptStream.Flush();
        encryptedSource = encryptStream.ToArray();
    }

    return encryptedSource;
}
```

It seems that the padding gives me 1 extra byte during decryption

Comment: Is the one byte a nul, `'\0'`? Can't you just strip those off? I think otherwise you'd have to store an expected length somewhere, of the whole file or of just the last encryption block. Or you can wrap the data in something else, e.g. a gzip stream, which will include the correct length. And why would this one byte stop you opening the XML??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

Now let's try to explain.

Let's say I have a file of 927 bytes.

What I do is to read this file and split it in pieces of 656 bytes. This byte array of 656 bytes is being encrypted. The second array will be 271 bytes.

In every block for encryption I used padding.  When decrypting, you will not be able to know in which block padding was used because every block now can be divided by 16 (because of the padding in the encryption). Basically I only want padding used for the last block(271).

so this is my new code:

```
public byte[] encryptData(byte[] source, string key, bool padding)
{
    byte[] encryptedSource = null;


    byte[] btKeyInBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, btKeyInBytes);

    AesManaged encryptor = new AesManaged();
    //encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CFB; 
    encryptor.KeySize = 128;          // in bits     
    encryptor.Key = new byte[128 / 8];  // 16 bytes for 128 bit encryption     
    encryptor.IV = new byte[128 / 8];
    if (padding) { encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; }
    else { encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.None; }


    using (MemoryStream encryptStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream encStream =
                   new CryptoStream(encryptStream,
                                    encryptor.CreateEncryptor(rfc.GetBytes(16),
                                                              rfc.GetBytes(16)),
                                    CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            //Read from the input stream, then encrypt and write to the output stream.
            encStream.Write(source, 0, source.Length);
        }
        encryptStream.Flush();
        encryptedSource = encryptStream.ToArray();
    }
    return encryptedSource;
}

public byte[] decryptData(byte[] source, string key,bool padding)
{
    byte[] encryptedSource = null;

    byte[] btKeyInBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, btKeyInBytes);

    AesManaged encryptor = new AesManaged();
    encryptor.Key = new byte[128 / 8];  // 16 bytes for 128 bit encryption     
    encryptor.IV = new byte[128 / 8];
    if (padding) { encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; }
    else { encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.None; }


    using (MemoryStream encryptStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream encStream =
                 new CryptoStream(encryptStream,
                                  encryptor.CreateDecryptor(rfc.GetBytes(16),
                                                            rfc.GetBytes(16)),
                                  CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            //Read from the input stream, then encrypt and write to the output stream.
            encStream.Write(source, 0, source.Length);
        }
        encryptStream.Flush();
        encryptedSource = encryptStream.ToArray();

    }

    return encryptedSource;
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Okay, **why** did you split your file in 656-byte blocks? (Why this strange number of 16·41, and why at all?)

Comment: I use this code for a pipeline component in biztalk. to avoid out of memory exceptions i encrypt and decrypt in blocks. basically it can be any number that you can divide by 16.

Comment: You can use the CryptoStream class in stream form (i.e. not with a MemoryStream underlying) and write always only some bytes, you don't have to create a new one for each block. Then the stream itself will take care of sending only full blocks. Alternatively, use PKCS#7-padding for every message (and use also a MAC).

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is padding, then `PaddingMode.Zeros` is about the worst choice, since zeros cannot always be reliably removed.  Better to use PKCS7 padding.

It is also possible that the encoding of end-of-line has changed between systems.  Some systems use a single byte while other systems use two bytes.  You really need to look at exactly what is in the decrypted file, byte by byte, as @Rup suggests.

Comment: For XML encryption, removing trailing zeros should be no problem, as they are not allowed at the end. Though you are right, PKCS#7 padding is a better idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help! the last byte is 0. When i change the code to padding PKCS7 i get: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed only with PaddingMode.Zeros i do not get any exceptions.

Comment: What padding mode is used to encrypt?  Padding must be the same at both ends.